# Incorrect browser output for simple Javascript - trying to test alert() function

Tags: javascript, html, function, browser, alert

I am just starting out on my JavaScript tutorial and it says to test this simple script out. However, I get the wrong output.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I should be getting an alert dialogue box. I have tried the following code on Chrome and Safari web browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Template</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript">

        alert("Hello World");

    </SCRIPT>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And the browser output I am getting is:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0
>   Arial;}} {*\generator Msftedit
>   5.41.15.1515;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 \par \par \tab \par \tab\tab \par \tab \par \tab\par \tab \par \tab\tab\par \tab \par \par \tab
>   \par \par }

Please does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: Are you saving your code as an RTF file? (You should save it as a plain text file.)

Comment: What you have done is, you might have created the file in microsoft word and saved as RTF?

Comment: Yes basically I was using word pad although it appeared that I was saving it as a html file it did not give me the option to select 'All files' but now using 'note pad' and problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using an evil Windows product to write your code.  Try using notepad instead.  Long story short: you're capturing hidden characters inserted by your editor.

Comment: Awesome man. Yes you are right I was using 'wordpad' instead Of 'notepad', ahh something so simple yet we learn. cheers

Comment: @Mr_leighman: you can use WordPad if you want, just save the file as plain text. (Notepad is a "Windows product" as well, although I don't know what its evil quotient is, compared to WordPad.)